# Fish EDITOR environment variable does not seem to work

Tags: shell, environment-variables, fish

I recently started using the Fish shell.

`echo $EDITOR` returns `vim`

But yet, when using programs that need to launch an editor and look for it in the `EDITOR` environment variable they don't seem to find anything.

As an example when using `pass edit` (from https://www.passwordstore.org/) it returns

`vi: command not found` (it uses vi as a fallback when nothing is set in the `EDITOR` env variable)

What did I miss?

Comment: I'm unaccustomed to the `fish` shell, but in most `sh`-like shells, you would need to `export` a shell variable for it to be accessible as an environment variable in child processes (or use `setenv` in `csh`). It's possible that the `EDITOR` variable that you have is just a shell variable and not an enviroment variable. I don't know what the equivalent of `export` in the `fish` shell is though.

Comment: In fish, it's `set -x EDITOR`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that a few programs look for the `$VISUAL` environment variable before the `$EDITOR` environment variable, so if you have both set, `$VISUAL` will take precedence.

Also note that shell variables are just that, variables in the shell language. You'd need to call commands with `EDITOR=preferred-editor` in their *environment* for them to pick it up.

Shells can map some of their variables to environment variables that are then passed as `var=value` in the environment of all the commands they execute. In `rc`-like shells, that's done for *all* shell variables, in Bourne-like shells, that's done with `export var`. In `csh`, you use `setenv var value` to set an environment variable. In `fish`, you use the `-x` option of `set`:

```
> set var value
> echo $var
value
> printenv var
>
```

A `$var` shell variable was set, but not exported (as `var=value`) to the environment passed to `printenv`.

```
> set -x var value2
> echo $var
value2
> printenv var
value2
```

This time, `printenv` did get a `var=value2` in the environment it received.

`printenv` is not a standard command but is commonly available. `env` is a standard command, so if your system doesn't have `printenv`, you could try:

```
env | grep -E '^(VISUAL|EDITOR)='
```

Though it could be fooled if you had variables with values such as `var=<newline>VISUAL=` or values larger than `LINE_MAX`.

Other options could be:

```
perl -le 'print $ENV{VISUAL}'
```

```
python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("VISUAL"))'
```

Also note that though it is highly unlikely to be the case here, it is possible to execute a command with more than one `var=value` for a given `var` in their environment.

For instance, you could do

```
execve("/path/to/cmd", ["cmd", "some arg"], ["VISUAL=vi", "VISUAL=emacs"])
```

What value `cmd` will consider the `VISUAL` environment variable as having will depend on how they scan that env var list they received upon `exceve()`. You'll find that some commands / libraries (like `libc`'s `getenv()`) will pick the first while some will pick the last. Some shells will map one of them to their corresponding env var but may leave the other one around and passed along in further executions.

So you could be doing `set -x VISUAL vim`, and `printenv` seeing `emacs` because `fish` was executed with both `VISUAL=vi`  and `VISUAL=emacs` and only modified the first `VISUAL` whilst `printenv` gives you the second.

For this kind of thing to happen though, you'd need something or someone actively trying to trick you, and after double checking, it seems `fish` is one of those shells that do remove the duplicates from the environment if any.

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed answer. Not only does it work, but I also understand why now. Yay!